# Why does the Eulerian approach become invalid for intersecting trajectories?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology

When studying cold dust (pressureless non relativistic matter) in cosmology with the Eulerian approach, one says that the equations are valid until the intersection of particles. Why? Is this because I can't distinguish between two particles in the same point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eulerian approach is to have a (time-dependent) vector-field. At each point the field tells you the direction of the particle. If two particles intersect, which means they come from different directions, and most likely go to different directions, you would have to assign two vectors at this point to the field. This is of course not possible.